# SE Toast/FancyOverlay Suppressor

Tags: script

StackExchange provides a variety of notices and toast messages, but sometimes they can get a bit annoying for experienced users.

This UserScript adds a Proxy to the two helper functions which cause these popups and conditionally runs the function or not based on the arguments.

### Preview

Nothing to see here (Literally. That's the point you won't see these things anymore)

### Installation

1. Install a UserScript extension (*e.g.* [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)) for your browser.
2. Install the UserScript [install](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/raw/main/SENoticesSuppressor.user.js) ([GitHub](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/blob/main/SENoticesSuppressor.user.js))

### Usage

The messages that are currently blocked are:

Toasts:

- 'You haven't voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!'
- 'Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.'

FancyOverlay:

- 'Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.'

There is nothing you need to do, these messages will simply no longer appear.

To block any additional messages simply add the message text to the appropriate Set. Naturally, removing values from either Set will restore the notices.

```javascript
const toastMessagesToSuppress = new Set([
    'You haven&#39;t voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!',
    'Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.'
]);

const fancyOverlayMessagesToSuppress = new Set([
    'Welcome back! If you found this question useful,\u003cbr/\u003edon\u0027t forget to vote both the question and the answers up.'
]);
```

### Code:

The [script](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/blob/main/SENoticesSuppressor.user.js) is written in JavaScript.

Feel free to submit issues as answers here or on [Github](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/issues).

Comment: "but sometimes they can get a bit annoying for experienced users" - and the award for the understatement of the century goes to...

Comment: Why does Zoe Stands With Ukraine get the award? That seems *completely* unfair, as she didn't even make the statement!